# iOS Email HTML With BaseURL

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have an HTML embedded in my app, and I want to be able to email it within the app.  I have the code below set up, and it will email the text from the Email, but not attach the images embedded with it.  I believe this is due to not having the baseURL set up properly but I'm not sure how to do that for the emailBody.  Any thoughts?

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Thanks" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"A prayer gift of thanks to you"];


    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"friend@example.com"];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = htmlString;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: Is it after sending, the `friend@example.com` does not see the image in his received email body?

Comment: Just in viewing it in the mail picker controller, and in receiving it.  Also, it is clipping off half of the signature line as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *emailBody = @"<html><body>";
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/arrioch/halloween/512/devil-icon.png' width = '64' height='64'/>"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br>"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"My text", @"")];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br>"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```